# T-SQL Loop through dates

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a list of dates (more than 100) where i need to sum a particular column for each of these dates. I know the below doesn't work but it shows what i'm trying to do...please help

```
USE FIND
select SUM(a.rm_result_as_pct_of_nav)
from rpt.rm_Report_History a 
where
a.analysis_date IN( '20160330','20160228','20160131')
and a.criteria_Set = 'Daily' and a.ptf_id = '10039'
and a.stat_def_id=397
```

There are no errors but I just get 1 total. I need the total per date, so i can see at the end of each month the pct_of_nav is x.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If so please post them

Comment: No errors but i just get 1 total...i need the total per date, so i can see at the end of each month the pct_of_nav is x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the sum and show the date;

```
SELECT
a.analysis_date
,SUM(a.rm_result_as_pct_of_nav) SumResult
FROM rpt.rm_Report_History a
WHERE a.analysis_date IN ('20160330','20160228','20160131')
    AND a.criteria_Set = 'Daily' 
    AND a.ptf_id = '10039'
    AND a.stat_def_id=397
GROUP BY a.analysis_date
```

If you don't want to restrict the dates then do something like this;

```
SELECT
a.analysis_date
,SUM(a.rm_result_as_pct_of_nav) SumResult
FROM rpt.rm_Report_History a
WHERE a.criteria_Set = 'Daily' 
    AND a.ptf_id = '10039'
    AND a.stat_def_id=397
GROUP BY a.analysis_date
```

Comment: again only gives 30th June results, not the others

Comment: Ok, could you update your question and include your sample data? I'm assuming that one of the fields in the where clause is restricting the data. Try it without the where clause to check that it's working. Then add in the clauses and see which one restricts the data to only the 30th of June.

Comment: yes my bad, the dates i specified were not avaialbe,,,you answered it thanks

Comment: Happy to help. Feel free to upvote and mark as accepted if this answer has resolved the issue.